# Can I store a counter across conversation in Inline Fulfillment Dialogflow editor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, count, dialogflow-es, fulfillment

I'm making a multiplayer quiz in dialogflow using the inline editor. For now, I have round 1 and 2 working but the score counting not yet.

So maybe it's stupid but I thought 'oh I will make a var and store a count in that. Every time a function is at a good answer de count will do ++ etc etc."

I made a snippet with 2 questions so you understand my problem. I've read much about oh you have to store it in user storage but I don't understand how. Already read the documentation of dialogflow but I'm not that much technical so it's hard.

```
  var pointsp1 = 0;
  var pointsp2 = 0;

//round 2 player 1

  function vraag1triva(agent) {  
  const goed = agent.parameters.goed;
  const fout = agent.parameters.any;


    if (goed=='tv tas') {
     pointsp1++;
      agent.add("<speak><audio src=\"https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/transportation/ship_bell.ogg\"></audio>uit welk land komt de avocado?</speak>");
    } else if (fout) {
        agent.add("Je antwoord is fout, het juiste antwoord was tv-tas,uit welk land komt de avocado?");
    }
  }
  //round 2 player 2
  function vraag2triva(agent) {  
    const goed = agent.parameters.goed;
    const fout = agent.parameters.any;
      if (goed=='mexico') {
        pointsp2++;
          agent.add("Goedzo, Mexico is het juiste antwoord. Van wie is het nummer Don't worry, be happy?");
      } else if (fout) {
          agent.add("Je antwoord is fout, het juiste antwoord was mexico, Van wie is het nummer Don't worry, be happy?");
      }
  }
 //score
  function totalscore(agent) {  
    if (pointsp1>pointsp2) {
      agent.add("Player 1 wins"); 
    }else if (pointsp1<pointsp2)
      agent.add("Player 2 wins");
  }
```

I expected that when I would call the function 'total scores'. It says which player had won the round according to the most good answers.

edit, tried user storage:

```
let conv = agent.conv(); // create an instance
    conv.data.pointspt1 = 0;
    conv.data.pointsp2 = 0;

   //score
  function totalscore(agent) {  
    if (conv.data.pointsp1>conv.data.pointsp2) {
      agent.add("Player 1 wins round 2"); 
    }else if (conv.data.pointsp1<conv.data.pointsp2)
      agent.add("Player 2 wins round2");
  }


//round 2 player 1

  function vraag1triva(agent) {  
  const goed = agent.parameters.goed;
  const fout = agent.parameters.any;

    if (goed=='tv tas') {
    //save score
      agent.add("<speak><audio src=\"https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/transportation/ship_bell.ogg\"></audio>uit welk land komt de avocado?</speak>");
      conv.user.storage.pointspt1++; 
    } else if (fout) {
        agent.add("Je antwoord is fout, het juiste antwoord was tv-tas,uit welk land komt de avocado?");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Since the user storage isn't working, did you enable the web & activity settings and enable the chrome history settings in the activity center? https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols

Answer (score 0):

You can store a count in Inline editor. There are two options for storing data and you can choose based on whether you want to save data within a conversation or across conversations. If it is within conversation (your game score for current session) use `conversationToken`. Example:

```
let conv = agent.conv(); // create an instance
conv.data.pointspt1 = 0;
conv.data.pointsp2 = 1;
const total = conv.data.pointspt1 + conv.data.pointspt2;
agent.add(`Your total score is ${total}`);
// If you want to save data across conversations
conv.user.storage.pointspt1 = 0; // This works only for verified users
```

Refer to the following link for more informations: [Save data in conversation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/save-data)

Comment: Thanks! sounds logical I don't get that much wiser from the link.

But i guess it will be something like this: (see edit in post above)

Comment: no it isn't unfortunately with the code in the edit above :(

Comment: in the code above both values are zero (equal) and your code is checking for smaller or greater. you are incrementing conv.user.storage which is different from conv.data